# problem with checkbox statuses

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have a problem, and I can't seem to work out how to solve it. I have two checkboxes, both of them have a value of 5. I just need to add the value of 5 to a variable when a checkbox is checked, and deduct 5, when it is unchecked. I've been using jQuery, but so far I've only managed to add 5 and it adds 10, when both of them are checked. It doesn't deduct anything as of now. Since I have a some radio buttons which I properly check, the code I have is this.

```
$(":checked").each(function(){
    if ($(this).attr("type") == "checkbox"){
        pricediff += 5;
    }
}
```

as the function each is used, it adds 10 when both of them are checked. This, of course, is not wanted. And it still has to deduct 5 when the checkbox is unchecked. I have no idea how to do that - I'm a bit of a noob to jQuery and JavaScript. Can anyone assist me? Thanks

P.S. this is not the exact code but just the jist of it.

Comment: To raise the chance people will help you, it's advised to accept some answers of your previous questions first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" class="test" />
<input type="checkbox" class="test" />
<input type="checkbox" class="test" />
<input type="checkbox" class="test" /><br />
<span id="result">0</span>
```

Script

```
$(function(){
    $("input:checkbox.test").click(function(){
        var checked = $("input:checkbox.test:checked").length;
        var checkedValue = checked * 5;

        $("#result").text(checkedValue)
    });
});
```

See a [**working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jHVAc/)

Comment: Thank you. That's the most reasonable answer. I know it works here, but in the context of my code, it doesn't work like it should, since there's a lot more values and they all have to be added on. And I can't just add checkedValue all the time. I have to know when to deduct. Thanks for your help though, you've lead me on to the right track.

Comment: indeed - see my example below.

Answer (score 2):

@rahul has a good answer, but this implies all checkboxes must have a value of 5.

Try this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2WJZ4/

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="test" value="5" />
<input type="checkbox" class="test" value="7" />
<input type="checkbox" class="test" value="2" />
<input type="checkbox" class="test" value="1" /><br />
<span id="result">0</span>
```

Script:

```
$(function(){
    $("input.test").change(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        var value = $this.val();
        var checked = $this.is(":checked");
        if (checked) value = -value;
        var $r = $('#result');
        $r.text( (+$r.text()) - value)
    });
});
```

PS. @rahul Awesome fiddle page!!!

Answer (score 1):

try something like this 
`var placediff;`
`function calc()`
`{`
`var n = $("input:checked").length;`
`pricediff = n*5;`
`}`
`$(":checkbox").click(calc);`

Comment: This is right. I checked in the context of my code and it didn't work. It does answer my exact question though, and it does work like I asked it to. Thank you.